# Connect to monetDb trough ssh tunnel

Tags: node.js, ssh-tunnel, monetdb, ssh2

I am trying to connect to MonetDb database, unsuccessfully though :(

I am trying to replicate [this](https://medium.com/@devontem/nodejs-express-using-ssh-to-access-mysql-remotely-60372832dd08) approach as much as I can.

Here is the code:

```
var MDB = require('monetdb')();
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var ssh = new Client();

const config = {... this one works...the problem is not here }

var db = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    ssh.on('ready', function() {
      console.log("SSH connection ready !!!");
      ssh.forwardOut('127.0.0.1', 12345, 'db7', 50000, function name(err, stream) {
          if(err){
              console.log(`${err}`);
          } else {
              console.log(`SSH connection established :)`);
              var conn = new MDB({
                host     : 'db7', 
                port     : 50000, 
                dbname   : 'db', 
                user     : 'user', 
                password : 'SupedDuperPass',
                language: 'sql'
            });
            // console.log(conn);
        
            var res = conn.connect("csrhub");
            console.log("Response: ", res);
          }
      });
    }).connect(config);
});
```

I receive the following messages from console:

> SSH connection ready !!!
>
> SSH forwarded...
>
> Response:  { state: 'pending' }
>
> (node:12496) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
>
> WARNING Socket error occurred: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db7 db7:50000
>
> WARNING Reconnect attempt 1/10 in 2 sec..
>
> WARNING Socket error occurred: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db7 db7:50000
>
> WARNING Could not connect to MonetDB: Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db7 db7:50000
>
> WARNING Reconnect attempt 2/10 in 2 sec..
>
> WARNING Socket error occurred: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db7 db7:50000
>
> WARNING Could not connect to MonetDB: Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db7 db7:50000
>
> WARNING Reconnect attempt 3/10 in 2 sec..

The ssh connection is successfully established  but I cant connect to MonetDb.

Please help me make it work.

Comment: Is there a SSH running on `127.0.0.1:12345` ?

Comment: @ValentinRoudge I am afraid not.
It should be running on the NodeJS-running-machine, right?